# How to send reset email to specific user using in-built django authentication system?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have created a small app in django which contains authentication feature to save data. I am using django default authentication system for password change and reset. While doing password reset, It sends a mail to the mail id specified in the form. But the problem is, it is fetching the first user's name and sending mail. So the password is being reset to the first user itself. How to send the mail using the specific username entered in the log in page?

urls.py:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from . import views

app_name = 'set_goals'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/about/$',views.about,name='about'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/download/$', views.download, name='download'),
    url(r'^login_user/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    url(r'^logout_user/$', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^password_change/$',auth_views.password_change,{'post_change_redirect':'set_goals:password_change_done'},name='password_change'),
    url(r'^password_change/done/$',auth_views.password_change_done,name='password_change_done'),
    url(r'^password_reset/$',auth_views.password_reset,{'email_template_name':'registration/password_reset_email.html',
                                                    'subject_template_name':'registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
                                                    'post_reset_redirect':'set_goals:password_reset_done',
                                                    },name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$',auth_views.password_reset_done,name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password_reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        auth_views.password_reset_confirm, {'post_reset_redirect':'set_goals:password_reset_complete'},name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),]
```

password_reset_mail.html:

```
{% autoescape off %}
To initiate the password reset process for your {{ user.get_username }} TestSite Account,
click the link below:

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'set_goals:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}

If clicking the link above doesn't work, please copy and paste the URL in a new browser
window instead.

Sincerely,
The TestSite Team
{% endautoescape %}
```

My question is, How to send the user id of the name typed in log in page? Do I have to create a custom view for this? Please help.